# create table from another table in different database in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, select, create-table

I have a database "temp" with table "A". I created new database "temp2".
I want to copy table "A" from "temp" to a new table in "temp2" . I tried this statement but it says I have incorrect syntax, here is the statement:

```
CREATE TABLE B IN 'temp2'
  AS (SELECT * FROM A IN 'temp');
```

Here is the error:

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IN'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IN'.

Anyone knows whats the problem?

Thanks in advance,

Greg

Comment: What if the table "A" is located in another server??

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I've not seen that syntax before. This is what I normally use.

```
SELECT * 
INTO temp2.dbo.B
FROM temp.dbo.A
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to qualify enough of the table name for SQL Server to be able to identify the correct table.

The name structure is `<server name>.<database name>.<schema>.<table>`. As both tables live on the same server you can dispense with that, but still need the rest:

```
SELECT * 
INTO temp2.dbo.B
FROM temp.dbo.A
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create a new table in another DB from the current DB, run the query.

```
CREATE TABLE `destination_database_name`.table_dummy AS (
SELECT * FROM currentDB.table
)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don,t want the data and only want the shcema of table without data then u can use this approach also...

```
SELECT * INTO temp2.dbo.b
FROM temp.dbo.a where 1=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Query should be:

```
SELECT * INTO temp2.dbo.b
FROM temp.dbo.a
```

Comment: I see my and @Martin's answers evolved into each other :)

Comment: Just as well as I think there is only one right syntax for this!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the data you can do:

```
SELECT TOP 0 * INTO temp2.dbo.b
FROM temp.dbo.a
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is by right click on table `A` from database `temp`, then click `Script Table as` => `CREATE to` => `New Query Editor Window`. This will create the script.

Then, change following 2 lines. and run it for new database.

```
USE [temp2]

....

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[B]

.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that SELECT INTO wont copy the indexes. If you want them too, you can generate script from source;run in the target db and do insert into

insert into temp2.dbo.b (columns)
select columns from temp.dbo.a